# Showing The jpeg of a graph returned from webservice

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services, google-maps, button

well i have written this code that allows user to pan the google map, select an area and then when he/she presses a button then the coordinates of the corner are passed to a webservice that returns the annotations inside that area and plots it on the map.

the app is working fine for the area selected.
Now i want to add a feature that on clicking the annotation, it returns to me a graph of those values.

This graph can be accessed from the webservice below,

```
http://hydrodata.info/graph/handler2.ashx?startDate=2010-10-01&endDate=2011-08-01&siteCode=NWISDV:13073000&variableCode=NWISDV:00060&serviceUrl=http://river.sdsc.edu/wateroneflow/NWIS/DailyValues.asmx?WSDL&height=500&width=500
```

where the siteCode,Variable code etc are obtained from another web service which i have with me.

so can anyone help me as to how do i show this graph on my app?

attached below is the code,

the main class is,

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(8);
    addListenerOnButton();

}
public void addListenerOnButton() 
{
     final MapView mapView;
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        MapView mapView;

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
                       public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

             for(int i=0;i<mapOverlays.size();i++)
             {
                 mapOverlays.remove(0);  
                }

        //mapView.getOverlays().clear(); //from here

              Drawable drawable = AndroidTestActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mapmarker);
              HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay1= new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,AndroidTestActivity.this);
              itemizedoverlay1.delOverlay();

             if(!mapOverlays.isEmpty()) 
             { 
             mapOverlays.clear(); 
             mapView.invalidate();
             }

        EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String parameter= text.getText().toString(); 

        EditText text2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String strdd=text2.getText().toString(); 
        EditText textmm2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText23);
        String strmm=textmm2.getText().toString(); 

        EditText textyy2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText24);
        String stryy=textyy2.getText().toString(); 

        String startDate=strdd+"/"+ strmm+"/"+ stryy; 


        EditText textedd2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText35);
        String stredd=textedd2.getText().toString(); 
        EditText textemm2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText36);
        String stremm=textemm2.getText().toString(); 

        EditText texteyy2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText37);
        String streyy=texteyy2.getText().toString(); 

        String endDate= stredd+"/"+ stremm+"/"+ streyy; 

        GeoPoint center = mapView.getMapCenter();


       float centerLatitude = (float)(center.getLatitudeE6())/1000000;
       float centerLongitude = (float)(center.getLongitudeE6())/1000000;


       GeoPoint mapTopLeft = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(0,0);
        topLatitude = (double)(mapTopLeft.getLatitudeE6())/1000000;
        leftLongitude = (double)(mapTopLeft.getLongitudeE6())/1000000;

       GeoPoint mapBottomRight= mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(width, height/2);
        bottomLatitude = (double)(mapBottomRight.getLatitudeE6())/1000000;
        rightLongitude = (double)(mapBottomRight.getLongitudeE6())/1000000;



        str= Double.toString(centerLatitude);
        str1=Double.toString(centerLongitude);
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(center, str, "center");
        itemizedoverlay1.addOverlay(overlayitem);


        str2= Double.toString(topLatitude);
        str3=Double.toString(leftLongitude);
        OverlayItem overlayitem1 = new OverlayItem(mapTopLeft, str2, "topLeft");
        itemizedoverlay1.addOverlay(overlayitem1);


        str4= Double.toString(bottomLatitude);
        str5=Double.toString(rightLongitude);
        OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(mapBottomRight, str4, "bottomRight");
        itemizedoverlay1.addOverlay(overlayitem2);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay1);
        dms=Double.toString(topLatitude)+";"+Double.toString(leftLongitude)+";"+Double.toString(bottomLatitude)+";"+Double.toString(rightLongitude);
        String[] arr=dms.split(";");

    for (int i=0; i<4 ; i++)
    {

        double value = Double.valueOf(arr[i]);
        if (value <0)
        {
            value=value*-1;
            int y = (int) value;
            double rest= value - y;
            String min_sec = Double.toString(rest);
            String min = min_sec.substring(2,4);   /* minutes */
            String sec = min_sec.substring(4,6);   /* seconds */
            minutes = (Double.valueOf(min)) / 60;   /* minutes DD */
            seconds = Double.valueOf(sec) / 3600;  
            double value1= y + minutes + seconds;
            value1=value1*-1;
            strtest=strtest+Double.toString(value1)+";";
           // pass[i]= value1;
        }
        else
        {
                int y1 = (int) value;
                double rest1= value - y1;
                String min_sec1 = Double.toString(rest1);
                String min1 = min_sec1.substring(2,4);   /* minutes */
                String sec1 = min_sec1.substring(4,6);   /* seconds */
                minutes = (Double.valueOf(min1)) / 60;   /* minutes DD */
                seconds = Double.valueOf(sec1) / 3600;  
                double value1= y1 + minutes + seconds;
                strtest=strtest+Double.toString(value1)+";";
              //  pass[i]= value1;
        }
    }
    strtest=Double.toString(a)+";"+Double.toString(b)+";"+Double.toString(c)+";"+Double.toString(d)+";"+parameter +";"+startDate+";"+endDate;
    Log.d("strtest strtest", "strtest strtest = "+strtest);
    Intent msgIntent = new Intent(AndroidTestActivity.this,Intentservice.class); 
    msgIntent.putExtra("strtest", strtest);  //arrlat_long
    startService(msgIntent); 

    //Dynamic registration Receiver
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_RECV_MSG);  
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);  
    receiver = new MessageReceiver();  
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);  
    IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(ACTION_OTHER_MSG);  
    filter2.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);  
    receiver = new MessageReceiver();  
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter2);  
}  }
        );
    }
  //Broadcast to receive 
public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{  
    @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {   

        Toast.makeText(context, "hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         if(arrlat_lat!= null)
           {
               arrlat_lat.clear();
           }

           if(arrlat_long!= null)                    //!arrlat_long.isEmpty()
           {
               arrlat_long.clear();
           }

        arrlat_long = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("codnt");  
        arrlat_lat = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("codntlat");  

      // text.setText(message);      

        Toast.makeText(context, arrlat_long.get(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    testoverlay();
    }  
} 
public void testoverlay()
{

  List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays(); 
  Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mapmarker);
   if (flag==0)
   { 

   HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);

   for(int i=0;i<arrlat_long.size();i++)
   {

        float lat = Float.parseFloat(arrlat_lat.get(i));
        float lng = Float.parseFloat(arrlat_long.get(i));

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lng * 1E6));
        lat1= lat;
        lon1= lng;
        str= Double.toString(lat1);
        str1=Double.toString(lon1);
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, str,str1);
        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

   }mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
   mapView.invalidate();
   flag++;
   }
   else
   {
       HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay12 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
         //  mapView.getOverlays().clear();
           for(int i=0;i<arrlat_long.size();i++)
           {

                float lat = Float.parseFloat(arrlat_lat.get(i));
                float lng = Float.parseFloat(arrlat_long.get(i));

                GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lng * 1E6));
                lat1= lat;
                lon1= lng;
                str= Double.toString(lat1);
                str1=Double.toString(lon1);
                OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, str,str1);
                itemizedoverlay12.addOverlay(overlayitem);

           }mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay12);
           mapView.invalidate();

   } }
@Override 
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() 
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return false;
 }
}
```

IntentService.java

```
public Intentservice()
{
    super("Intentservice");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
{
      String strxmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,par,startDate,endDate;
        String str=intent.getExtras().getString("strtest");
        Log.d("onHandleIntent", "onHandleIntent onHandleIntent= "+str);
        String[] arrtelog=str.split(";");
         if(arrtelog.length >3)
            {
              strxmin=arrtelog[0];
              xmax=arrtelog[1];
              ymin=arrtelog[2];
              ymax=arrtelog[3];
              par=arrtelog[4];
              startDate=arrtelog[5];
              endDate=arrtelog[6];
              Log.d("onHandleIntent", "onHandleIntent strxmin= "+strxmin);
              Log.d("onHandleIntent", "onHandleIntent strxmin= "+xmax);
              Log.d("onHandleIntent", "onHandleIntent strxmin= "+ymin);
              Log.d("onHandleIntent", "onHandleIntent strxmin= "+ymax);
              Log.d("onHandleIntent", "onHandleIntent strxmin= "+par);
              Log.d("onHandleIntent", "onHandleIntent strxmin= "+startDate);
              Log.d("onHandleIntent", "onHandleIntent strxmin= "+endDate);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
         String Url = "http://hiscentral.cuahsi.org/webservices/hiscentral_1_1.asmx/GetSeriesCatalogForBox2";
         if(!Url.endsWith("?"))
         {
                Url += "?";
         }

         List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);   
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xmin",xmax)); //ymax
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xmax",ymax)); //xmax
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ymin",ymin)); //strxmin
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ymax", strxmin)); //ymin
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("networkIDs", ""));
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("conceptKeyword", par));
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("beginDate", startDate));
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("endDate", endDate));
         String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "utf-8");
         Url += paramString;
         try 
            {
               HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Url); 
               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
               HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
               HttpEntity httpentity = response.getEntity();

               if(httpentity == null)
               {

               }
               else
               {
               responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
               XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
               factory.setValidating(false);
               XmlPullParser myxml = factory.newPullParser();
               InputStream raw = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseBody.getBytes());
               myxml.setInput(raw, null);
               int eventType = myxml.getEventType();


               if(!arrlat_lat.isEmpty())
               {
                   arrlat_lat.clear();
               }

               if(!arrlat_long.isEmpty())                    //!arrlat_long.isEmpty(),, arrlat_long!= null
               {
                   arrlat_long.clear();
               }


               while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
               {
              if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) 
                 {

                     Log.d("ParseXmlActivity", "In start document");
                 }
                 else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) 
                 {
                     if (myxml.getName().equals("latitude"))
                        {
                            str="";
                            str  =  myxml.nextText().toString();
                             Log.d("ParseXmlActivity", "In start tag = "+str);
                             arrlat_lat.add(str);
                        }
                        if (myxml.getName().equals("longitude"))
                        {
                            str = myxml.nextText().toString();
                             Log.d("ParseXmlActivity", "In start tag = "+str);
                             arrlat_long.add(str);
                        }

               }

               eventType = myxml.next();

       } 
               }
               }
       catch (XmlPullParserException e) 
       {
       } 
       catch (IOException e)
       {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
         {

         }
       //  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_RECV_MSG); 
       //  filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);  
         //receiver = new MessageReceiver();  
      //   registerReceiver(receiver, filter); 


       if(arrlat_long.size()>0)
       {
       Log.d("TEST TESTTEST", "In start TESTTEST = "+arrlat_long.get(0)+" $$$ "+arrlat_long.size());
       Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();  
       broadcastIntent.setAction(ACTION_RECV_MSG);  
       broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);        
       broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("codnt", arrlat_long);  //arrlat_long
       broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("codntlat", arrlat_lat);  //arrlat_lat
       sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
       }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use display.getSize(size); to get the size of screen